# Double variable substitution in tcl

Tags: variables, tcl, substitution, expr

I am getting an error **invalid character "."** while running following code in tcl shell :

```
set var "p.txt_bc"
set p.txt_bc 1
expr $$var
```

invalid character "." in expression "$p.txt_bc"

How to handle the "." character here so that the output is 1 ?
I know I can replace the "." with something else to somehow make it work but is there a way to get the expected output without any substitution done to "." ?

Comment: Hint: you need to add 4 spaces in front of code to make stackoverflow format it correctly

Answer (score 1):

The `$$var` doesn't do double substitution. It puts a `$` in front of the contents of `var`.  That results in the literal expression `$p.txt_bc`, which is syntactically invalid because `.` isn't an operator in Tcl's expression language.

To do double substitution, you should use `[set]` for the outer layer (and brace your expression so that Tcl  can compile it, please), like this:

```
expr { [set $var] }
```

However, experience suggests that there are usually better approaches than using double substitution. In particular, most cases are better addressed by using either associative arrays or `upvar`.

```
set var "p.txt_bc"
set data(p.txt_bc) 1
expr { $data($var) }
```

```
set var "p.txt_bc"
set p.txt_bc 1
upvar 0 $var v
expr { $v }
```

The version with `upvar` is more common when the variable is in a different scope to the current one, and `upvar 0` isn't really recommended at the global level as it isn't easy to undo (because most operations on variables work on the alias as if it was the target).

Comment: We have discussed doing double substitution with `$$`, but have always decided not to as it encourages confusing usage. It would also break some existing code, but that wasn't the core consideration.

Comment: Also, once you use `[set $...]`, you probably don't need `expr` round the outside. Unless you want the "try to convert the result to a standard form number if you can but no worries if you can't" semantics.